# Вывод текста в div

Tags: javascript, html

Всем привет! прошу вашего помощи или "пинка" в нужном направлении и  сильно не ругайте с javascript только на стадии изучения =)
Есть страничка

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var about_bears = "Медведи - это такие крупные толстолапые звери, обитают в лесах.";

var about_lions = "Львы - это такие крупные звери из семейства кошачих, обитают в Африке.";

var about_cats = "Кошки - это такие некрупные звери из семейства кошачих, давным-давно одомашены людьми, и, следовательно, обитают даже на МКС.";

</script>

</head>

<body>

<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('div_for_insert').innerHTML = about_bears">Медведи</a>

<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('div_for_insert').innerHTML = about_lions">Львы</a>

<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('div_for_insert').innerHTML = about_cats">Кошки</a>

<div id="div_for_insert">

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

где при нажатии на ссылку срабатывает скрипт и добавляет в div тест. Вопрос в том, как сделать так что бы выводить больше количество текста. Так-как если текст не умещается в строку он его переносит на другую например:

```
var about_cats = "Кошки - это такие некрупные звери из семейства кошачих,(много текста и произошел перенос текста на другую строчку)
 давным-давно одомашены людьми, и, следовательно, обитают даже на МКС.";
```

и получается так что скрипт уже не видит перенесенный текст на другую строчку.
или если есть возможность как сделать так что бы он брал текст из файла и также добавлял в div ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Что делать с длинной строкой

Составляйте эту строку из серии маленьких:

```
var about_cats = "Кошки - это ..."+
    "давным-давно ..."+
    "в далекой-предалекой галактике...";
```

В дальнейшем будет полезно хранить данные отдельно от кода - json, xml файлы или получение данных из БД в этом помогут

#### Как хранить и получать данные отдельно:

1. выложить в публичную папку вашего сайта data.json c содержимым:

   ```
    {
       "about_bears": "...",
       "about_lions": "...",
       "about_cats": "..."
    }
   ```
2. Получить данные (например, с помощью Jquery.ajax) и запомнить их:

   ```
   <script>
   var mytexts;
   $.get("data.json", function(data){
       mytexts=data;
   });
   </script>
   ```
3. Использовать запомненные данные:

   ```
   (...).innerHTML = mytexts["about_bears"]
   ```

Comment: Блин все так просто =) спасибо большое =) а насчет добавления текста из фала не подскажете?

Comment: это понятно, просто это простенький сайт на котором редко будет редактироваться что-то =) поэтому такой примитивный подход =)

Comment: @Ghostkhimki С чтением из файла будут проблемы. Браузер не даст, ибо небезопасно. А вывод всякий раз окошка для выбора файла в данном случае будет неправильным решением.

Comment: @Ghostkhimki дополнил ответ. Но товарищ kff частично прав, с этим могут быть проблемы, но скорее не из-за безопасности, а из-за сложности для начинающего

Comment: @kff Ajax довольно безопасен, и брать постоянно из одного и того же места (это такой же ресурс, как и изображения)

Comment: @MiKeBu Это если файл на сервере. А если читать локальный? `Chrome` и  `Firefox` не дают.

Comment: да если смотреть со стороны безопасности, то оба варианта они не безопасны.

Comment: @kff, верно. Но, во-первых, человек уточнил, что это "простенький сайт". А во-вторых, клиентский скрипт будет выполняться у клиента, у которого не будет **своих** локальных файлов с **нашими** данными)

Comment: @MiKeBu Ok. Согласен.

Answer (score 1):

Многострочный текст в JavaScript можно ввести следующим образом:

```
var about_cats = "Кошки - это такие некрупные звери из семейства " + 
                 "кошачих, давным-давно одомашены людьми, " +
                 "и, следовательно, обитают даже на МКС.";
```

Или же так:

```
var about_cats = "Кошки - это такие некрупные звери из семейства \
кошачих, давным-давно одомашены людьми, \
и, следовательно, обитают даже на МКС.";
```

А ещё можно воспользоваться тем, что несколько пробельных символов подряд в HTML отображаются как один и записать так:

```
var about_cats = "Кошки - это такие некрупные звери из семейства \
                  кошачих, давным-давно одомашены людьми, \
                  и, следовательно, обитают даже на МКС.";
```

(Символ `\` должен быть последним в строке!)

Answer (score 1):

Хорошим тоном считается не хранить в исходниках контент. Выносите данные в отдельные файлы и получайте контент через ajax. Сам обработчик стоит вынести в отдельную функцию, а заполучить нужные данные можно, например, с помощью jQuery. Имя запрашиваемого файла можно вынести в отдельную переменную about.

```
// Универсальная функция загрузки контента в блок
window.loadTxt = function(about) {
  // Асинхронный запрос текстового файла
  jQuery.get("myStories/"+about+".txt", function(content) {
    document.getElementById('div_for_insert').innerHTML = content;
  }); 
};
```

HTML в таком случае будет выглядеть, примерно, так:

```
<a href="#" onclick="loadTxt('cats');return false;">Кошки</a>
```

Рассматривая более качественный уровень, можно в принципе избавится от аттрибута onclick и навешивать события через javascript-код. Здесь советую полностью перейти на функционал jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function() { // По готовности документа
    var themeLoader = function(about) { // Инициализируем функцию загрузчик
      // Асинхронный запрос текстового файла
      jQuery.get("myStories/"+about+".txt", function(content) {
        $('#div_for_insert').html(content);
      }); 
    };
    $("a[theme]") // Находим все A с аттрибутом [data-theme]
    .click(function(){ // Вешаем обработчик события click на них
       themeLoader($(this).attr("theme")); // Загружаем файл с именем, хранящемся в аттрибуте data-theme
    });
});
```

В HTML не остается ничего, кроме данных о требуемых файлах.

```
<a href="#" data-theme="cats">Кошки</a>
<a href="#" data-theme="fleas">Блошки</a>
<a href="#" data-theme="midge">Мошки</a>
<div id="div_for_insert"></div>
```

Comment: с HTML разметкой я понял, и примерно понял со скриптом, но не совсем понял как скрипт поймет какой файл загружать и вставлять в див. Он ищет в папке "myStories" файлы с названием указанным в ссылке и расширением .txt и если находит совпадение то выводит их в див?

Comment: Клиентский Javascript увы пока что не способен ничего искать в файловой системе, он просто запрашивает файл с конкретным именем, предполагая, что он существует. Имена файлов у нас формируются на основе атрибута data-theme. Скрипт перебирает каждый тэг `<a />` в котором есть data-theme, забирает значение этого атрибута и формирует на основе него ссылку на файл.

Answer (score 0):

и всеже немного не разобрался с добавлением из файла текста

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Зодиаки</title>
<link href="design/design.css"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><!--подключение дизайна-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script><!--подключение jqury проект делаю в visual studia 2012 библиотеку подключал из среды-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/dobavlenie.js"></script><!--это подключение функции-->
</head>
<body>
<div id="body">
    <div id="header">
        <h1>Название сайта</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="Menu">
            <table>
                <tr><td><a href="#" data-theme="cats">Кошки</a></td></tr><!--тут мы нажимаем ссылку-->
                <tr><td><a href="#" data-theme="cats">Блошки</a></td></tr>
                <tr><td><a href="#" data-theme="cats">ложки</a></td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div id="content-2">
            <div id="div_for_insert"><!--Здесь получаем текст-->
```

Сама функция

```
$(document).ready(function () { // По готовности документа
var themeLoader = function (about) { // Инициализируем функцию загрузчик
    // Асинхронный запрос текстового файла
    jQuery.get("contents/" + about + ".txt", function (content) {//contents это если я правильно понял место где лежат мои документы
        $('#div_for_insert').html(content);
    });
};
$("a[theme]") // Находим все A с аттрибутом [data-theme]
.click(function () { // Вешаем обработчик события click на них
    themeLoader($(this).attr("theme")); // Загружаем файл с именем,      хранящемся в аттрибуте data-theme
});
});
```

создана отдельная папка contents в которой лежит файл cats.txt и при нажатии на ссылку "кошки" ничего не происходит.

Comment: Используя отладчик вашего браузера, сравните с ожидаемым: имя файла из атрибута, целый путь до файла, содержимое файла